# How return empty string, if the result is null

Tags: c#

```
return results.Select(x => new {                
            VillageName = x.VillageName,
            GroupID = x.GroupID,
            GroupName = x.GroupName,
            CenterID = x.CenterID,
            CenterName = x.CenterName,
        }).ToList<object>();
```

Comment: if CenterName and group name is null. Need to return an empty string

In c# 6.0, x?.CenterName -> return null value

Comment: I assume the `??` isnt working for you in this scenario? `x?.CenterName ?? ""`

Comment: I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`null-coalescing operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

```
x?.CenterName ?? string.Empty
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can implement C# ternary (? :) Operator.**
The syntax of ternary operator is:

```
Condition ? Expression1 : Expression2;
```

---

The Expressions below first checks for null conditions and if the condition is null, the value is set to empty.

```
return results.Select(x => new {                
            VillageName = x.VillageName,
            GroupID = x.GroupID,
            GroupName = x.GroupName  == null ? "" : x.GroupName,
            CenterID = x.CenterID,
            CenterName = x.CenterName == null ? "" : x.CenterName,
        }).ToList<object>();
```

or else you can use **"The null-coalescing operator(??)"** like:

```
CenterName = x.CenterName ?? "", //check and returns empty string if CenterName is null
```

Comment: This code works well. I am even applying same method but how come people down vote my answer  without even analyzing and testing it. Addition of comment for down vote with your reason would be greater. And yes this code works well.